# Symfony 6 (php8) XLIFF plurals now working

Tags: symfony, xliff, symfony6, symfony-translator

I'm working with Symfony 6.1.1 + php8.1.7 and have a problem with translations (XLIFF)

If the translation file is without translation all fine but pluralization won't work correctly with the translation key in the file

Translation call in Twig

```
{{ "{0}Any item found|{1}One item found|]1,Inf[ Found %count% items" | trans({'%count%': paginated_data.totalItemCount}) }}
```

Result with deleted translation from .xlf
[image]

And result with existing translation in the file (In the picture you can see, that translator gives the translation from the correct target block)

[image: result with existing translation in file]

There is part of the xliff file with translation

```
<trans-unit id="Y9p7sja1" resname="{0}Any item found|{1}One item found|]1,Inf[ Found %count% items">
    <source>{0}Any item found|{1}One item found|]1,Inf[ Found %count% items</source>
    <target>{0}Any item found1|{1}One item found2|]1,Inf[ Found %count% items3</target>
</trans-unit>
```

In debug panel, all is fine and Symfony says that pluralization working
[image: In debug panel all is fine and Symfony says that pluralization working]

Comment: Are you using the ICU translator or the regular one? How's the file named?

Comment: messages+intl-icu.en.xlf - its file autogenerated by symfony. And as i can write in question - all works with translations, problem only with plural from translations

Comment: Then, you are using the wrong message format, since its named `+intl-icu` you are supposed to [use the ICU format](https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation/message_format.html#pluralization).

Comment: File name is correct because if its not any of my translation would't work. But all translations except plurals are working from my file. And as I wrote upper, the filename generated by symfony and I dont renamed it

Comment: Yes, the file name is correct _if you are using the ICU format_, which you are, because it's the name what determines which one is used. See [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation/message_format.html#using-the-icu-message-format). And as you can [see here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.html#message-format), the tip box states: "If you **don't** use the ICU format...". Either change the message format or remove the `+intl-icu` from the file name to go back to the old format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer much simplest than i've expected.

Symofny XLIFF format for translations doesn't support pecent "%" sign for mark variables, it means that you must to change percent to some another sign like bracers "{}" and it's going to be work.

> In the previous translation format, placeholders were often wrapped in % (e.g. %name%). This % character is no longer valid with the ICU MessageFormat syntax, so you must rename your parameters if you are upgrading from the previous format.

```
<trans-unit id="Y9p7sja1" resname="{0}Any item found|{1}One item found|]1,Inf[ Found {count} items">
    <source>{0}Any item found|{1}One item found|]1,Inf[ Found {count} items</source>
    <target>{0}Any item found1|{1}One item found2|]1,Inf[ Found {count} items3</target>
</trans-unit>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your xlf should look like this:

```
<unit id="Y9p7sja1" name="plural_items">
    <segment>
        <source>plural_items</source>
        <target>{items, plural, =0 {Any item found} =1 {One item found} other {Found # items}}</target>
    </segment>
</unit>
```

And in Twig:

```
{{ 'plural_items'|trans({'items': paginated_data.totalItemCount}) }}
```